# Schema.org in Microdata or in JSON-LD?

Tags: seo, microdata, schema.org, json-ld

Should I use Microdata markup on my blog or should I put just an JSON-LD with all info, or is using both the best option?

A bit of explanation. I am trying to mark up my blog and I manage to get to 1 error left in "Structured Data Testing Tool". The error left is a publisher meta. Now I don't want to add blog info at the bottom of the post. I used Organization meta in header where my logo is, but testing tool doesn't take it into account.

Should I add JSON-LD duplicating all info and adding publisher data or should I use just JSON-LD and not bother with marking whole page?

Comment: Do both. Adding JSON format for mark up cant be considered as duplicate.

Comment: @Suri Have you tried what you're suggesting with the Structured Data Testing Tool? The tool shows it will duplicate the data which is almost certainly going to give the wrong impression to a parser.

Comment: Just a few days ago, I noticed Google's documentation now stating they recommend using JSON-LD over inlined attributes.

Comment: @Rob they also recently added "rich cards" and a report in webmaster tools. Those can only be triggered using JSON-LD. One thing though that i am not sure about is whether they support schema.org (and/or JSON-LD) breadcrumbs. We are still using the ancient data-vocab for those, since they did not support schema crumbs, last i knew. Has anyone got crumbs to apear with schema.org via JSON-LD?

Comment: @dhaupin That's another thing I read at the same time. Breadcrumbs will not work with JSON-LD and rich cards. I don't recall any other detail than that.

Comment: Can you link source. Also isnt this json-ld breadcrumbs? https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/breadcrumbs#use_cases

Comment: @klo those are def the ones. Unfortunately Google has a habit of making examples that aren't supported/live in SERPs yet, so it's unclear. In our site we have those as well as data-vocabulary style crumbs, since those data-vocab crumbs were the only ones that displayed in SERP even ~1 year ago. We would like to remove the data-vocab markup if the JSON-LD crumbs work (they validate in GWT), but I'm not sure if G actually displays them in SERP yet. I haven't run into any live examples in basic travels, and since this is a production site, I wouldn't want them to go away.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the organisation markup using itemref. Add an `id` to the organisation markup, then use `itemref="yourid"` at the top of your markup which needs to include the organisation.

Don't duplicate your markup with JSON-LD; use one or the other.

Comment: Based on comments and your answer doing markup and json is considered duplicating. Any idea what is better?

Comment: @klo See what I said about itemref in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the organisation info is static all across your blogs then you may define those properties using meta tags. It will not be considered as hidden content since the info is present on the page.

sample code:

```
<span itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
<meta itemprop="name" content="XYZ Org"/>
</span>
```